# Website logos for twitter, youtube etc

Tags: css, html, icons

I am trying to modify some website code that I have got from a template. In the css file i have a number of lines of code which look as follows - and i assume these are the logos to be referenced;

```
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Icons                                                                         */
/* Powered by Font Awesome by Dave Gandy | http://fontawesome.io                 */
/* Licensed under the SIL OFL 1.1 (font), MIT (CSS)                              */
/*********************************************************************************/
.fa {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .fa.solo {
    }

        .fa.solo span {
            display: none;
        }

    .fa:before {
        display:inline-block;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    }

    .fa-lg{font-size:1.3333333333333333em;line-height:.75em;vertical-align:-15%}
    .fa-2x{font-size:2em}
    .fa-3x{font-size:3em}
    .fa-4x{font-size:4em}
    .fa-5x{font-size:5em}
    .fa-apple:before{content:"\f179"}
    .fa-windows:before{content:"\f17a"}
    .fa-android:before{content:"\f17b"}
    .fa-linux:before{content:"\f17c"}
    .fa-dribbble:before{content:"\f17d"}
    .fa-skype:before{content:"\f17e"}
    .fa-foursquare:before{content:"\f180"}
    .fa-trello:before{content:"\f181"}
    .fa-female:before{content:"\f182"}
    .fa-male:before{content:"\f183"}
    .fa-gittip:before{content:"\f184"}
    .fa-sun-o:before{content:"\f185"}
    .fa-moon-o:before{content:"\f186"}
    .fa-archive:before{content:"\f187"}
    .fa-bug:before{content:"\f188"}
```

The issue i am having is that the logos do not appear on the webpage. Does the slash indicate that in the current directory there should be image f181,f182 and so on or do these values represent something else.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think `content:"\foo"` has a designated character in a font-family. So I think if you want to add a new logo or icon to font-awesome, you must also change the .ttf, .otf, .svg, etc. to make it work and I won't recommend it.

Comment: your question is not getting....can u share your test webpage link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. These codes are from font awesome family. Down load the font awesome and link to your webpage. It will work for you.

[Download Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)